# GridPane : Change grid line color

Tags: javafx

How can i change the grid lines color / can i change the grid lines color?
Cant seem to find a css solution.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619867/how-to-make-gridpanes-lines-visible

Comment: Use the posted link but try changing the color from black to the color you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css it work for me :

```
.mygridStyle Line {
  -fx-stroke   : red;
}
```

then you attach the css class with the scene builder or with myGrid.getStyleClass().add("mygridStyle");

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of the separation line?

Answer (score 1):

As stated
[in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892646/adding-borders-to-gridpane-javafx)
you shouldn't use GridPane to paint grid lines, you need to put content inside the cells, and then specify content borders. The visible grid line property if for debugging only, see [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#gridLinesVisibleProperty).