# How to not show grid lines in merged cells

Tags: javafx

I have GridPane in my JavaFX window and I span two columns.

When I click on grid lines visible in scenebuilder there is line in the middle of merged cells.

How can I remove or not show this line? [image]

Comment: Don't use `gridLinesVisible` in production code; it is for [debug purposes only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#gridLinesVisibleProperty).

Comment: And what should I use when I wanna see lines ?

Comment: but .. it's for debugging only, why would you bother? Time invested on such a marginality is utterly wasted, IMO

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach: In this approach, I make the `GridPane's` background black. Then I stretch each `Node` to fill their `Cell` and make the `Node's` background white. Also on the `GridPane`, I set all the `Insets` to 5 and the `VGap` and `HGap` to 5. **I suggest you use `CSS` and take @James_D's approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619867/how-to-make-gridpanes-lines-visible).**

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane hgap="5.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" vgap="5.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Label" GridPane.columnSpan="2147483647" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

But I would suggest you use `CSS` and follow @James_D's approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619867/how-to-make-gridpanes-lines-visible).

[image]